# How To Get How Long Ago An Annotation Was Placed iOS

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

So I am working with the `iOS Mapkit`, and part of the application requires me to show long ago an annotation was placed when somebody taps on it. So far I've tried this:

```
    //MARK: Report Date And Time Details
    let ReportTime = NSDate()
    let TimeStamp = NSDateFormatter()
    TimeStamp.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
    TimeStamp.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
    TimeStamp.stringFromDate(ReportTime)
```

And then set the description of the annotation to `Report Time`. Instead of doing this, I would like for the annotation to say "53,54,55 Minutes Ago etc." Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

Thanks All!

Comment: Try a `NSDateIntervalFormatter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. To get the time elapsed, I'd suggest using a `NSDateComponentsFormatter`:

   ```
   let formatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()
   formatter.allowedUnits = [.Hour, .Minute]
   formatter.unitsStyle = .Full

   let string = formatter.stringFromDate(date1, toDate: date2)
   ```

   That generates a string that looks like:

   > 2 hours, 1 minute
2. If you just want the callout to show you the elapsed time, the easiest way is to define a custom annotation with a computed property for `title` (or `subtitle`, whichever you prefer). For example:

   ```
   class CustomAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
       let startDate = NSDate()
       var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
       var subtitle: String?

       init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
           self.coordinate = coordinate
           super.init()
       }

       var title: String? {
           let formatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()
           formatter.allowedUnits = [.Hour, .Minute]
           formatter.unitsStyle = .Full

           let elapsedString = formatter.stringFromDate(startDate, toDate: NSDate())!

           return "Added \(elapsedString) ago"
       }
   }
   ```

   Note, the key here is that I'm using a computed property, not a stored property for `title` that you get with `MKPointAnnotation`. This ensures that each time the callout is presented, it re-retrieves the property, and the `NSDateComponentsFormatter` will recalculate the appropriate string representation of the elapsed time.

Clearly, you can change this as you see fit (e.g. is `startDate` really just when you created the annotation, or is it some stored property that you can set from your data source; you can change the initializer to pass additional properties; etc.), but this illustrates the basic idea.

[image]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117984/discussion-between-rob-and-user154248).